# Display tooltip from JavaScript.push method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, push

I was watching a youtube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJY8YUjFd58) on creating tooltips and I was able to get everything working in a flat html file with everything inline and with separate js/css. But what I haven't been able to do is use the JavaScript push method to display the same data in an html page.

I am using JavaScript to send the HTML table and inline CSS to the main HTML page (tt_hvr.html). The CSS seems to work but I cannot get the hover text inside the  element to show up. I have posted the files. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the hover to display the text that is inside the div? I have posted the three files below (tt_hvr.html, tt_hvr.js, tt_hvr1.js). Thanks in advance.

tt_hvr.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p id='data_here'></p>

</body>
<script src='tt_hvr.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='tt_hvr1.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

tt_hvr.js

```
   var hvrinfo = [];
   hvrinfo.push("<style type='text/css'>");
   hvrinfo.push("td {color: sienna;}");

   //Testing the tooltip begin.
   hvrinfo.push("   .hvrtip0{");
   hvrinfo.push("       margin-left:auto;");
   hvrinfo.push("       margin-right:auto;");
   hvrinfo.push("       margin-top:auto;");
   hvrinfo.push("       /*width:250px; */");
   hvrinfo.push("       background-color:#ffffff;");
   hvrinfo.push("       color:#000000;");
   hvrinfo.push("       padding:auto;");
   hvrinfo.push("       text-align:left;");
   hvrinfo.push("       }");
   hvrinfo.push("   .tooltip00{");
   hvrinfo.push("       position:absolute; /*Allows it to be anywhere on the page  without interrupting any other elements on the page.*/");
   hvrinfo.push("       z-index:2;");
   hvrinfo.push("       width:auto;");
   hvrinfo.push("       padding:5px;");
   hvrinfo.push("       background-color:#ffff00;");
   hvrinfo.push("       border:2px solid #000000;");
   hvrinfo.push("       border-radius:15px; //Rounding the corners on the box.");
   hvrinfo.push("       -moz-border-radius:15px; /*Firefox*/");
   hvrinfo.push("       display:none; /*Hide from page so that it will only be shown on hover.*/");
   hvrinfo.push("       }");
   hvrinfo.push("   td.hvrtip0{");
   hvrinfo.push("       background-color:#c0c0c0;");
   hvrinfo.push("       border:2px solid #e0e0e0;");
   hvrinfo.push("   }");
   hvrinfo.push("   table,td,th");
   hvrinfo.push("   {");
   hvrinfo.push("       border:1px solid black;");
   hvrinfo.push("   }");
   hvrinfo.push("   table");
   hvrinfo.push("   {");
   hvrinfo.push("       width:50%;");
   hvrinfo.push("       border-collapse:collapse;");
   hvrinfo.push("   }");
   hvrinfo.push("   th");
   hvrinfo.push("   {");
   hvrinfo.push("       height:50px;");
   hvrinfo.push("   }");
   hvrinfo.push("   #redthis");
   hvrinfo.push("   {");
   hvrinfo.push("       color:red;");
   hvrinfo.push("   }");
   //Testing the tooltip end.

   //Pushing the table begin.
   hvrinfo.push("</style>");
   hvrinfo.push("<table border='1'><tr><th>Row1</th><th>Row2</th><th>Row3</th></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td class='hvrtip0'>Cell 01</td><td>Cell 02</td><td>Cell 03</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 04</td><td>Cell 05</td><td>Cell 06</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 07</td><td>Cell 08</td><td class='hvrtip0'>Cell 09</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 10</td><td>Cell 11</td><td>Cell 12</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 13</td><td>Cell 14</td><td>Cell 15</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 16</td><td>Cell 17</td><td>Cell 18</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 19</td><td>Cell 20</td><td>Cell 21</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 22</td><td>Cell 23</td><td>Cell 24</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 25</td><td>Cell 26</td><td>Cell 27</td></tr>");
   hvrinfo.push("<tr><td>Cell 28</td><td>Cell 29</td><td>Cell 30</td></tr></table>");
   //Pushing the table end.

   //Information for the tooltips begin.
   hvrinfo.push("   <div class='tooltip00'>");
   hvrinfo.push("       1. RT conducts patient evaluation following <b id='redthis'>Eval & Treat Algorithm</b>.<br />");
   hvrinfo.push("       2. Level of Patients Asthma Control and current medications determined by RT.<br />");
   hvrinfo.push("       3. If Indicated, follow <b id='redthis'>Aerosolized medication Algorithm</b>.<br />");
   hvrinfo.push("       4. Plan constructed for therapy Pre-Op / Post-Op. If poorly controlled, advised or adminster step up in therapy (glucocorticoids).");
   hvrinfo.push("   </div>");
   //Information for the tooltips end.

   var hvrjoin = hvrinfo.join("");
   document.getElementById("data_here").innerHTML = hvrjoin;
```

tt_hvr1.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hvrtip0").hover(function(){//Hover on the class. This works on all classes in the document.
        //mouse enters
            $(".tooltip00").css("display","block");
    },function(){
        //mouse leaves
            $(".tooltip00").css("display","block");
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        var mx = event.pageX+15;
        var my = event.pageY+15;
        $(".tooltip00").css("left",mx+"px").css("top",my+"px");
    });
 });
```

Comment: I don't think this is the way to do it. you've a `<table>` as well as a stylesheet inside a `<p>` element… i couldn't find an element with class `hvrtip0` in there either.

Comment: What am I missing? Why go through the trouble of creating an array with css, html and JS when you can just load them in your main page?

Comment: @Rob when you load the jQuery script before your JS files it works as blgt suggested. Also I guess you should set display property to 'none' to make the tooltip invisible in mouse leave function.

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo on the mouse leave display.

Comment: @Ron (Why go through the trouble of creating an array with css, html and JS when you can just load them in your main page?) I needed to use the push method because that is how we display data in the electronic medical record EMR at work. I was able to get it to display as you suggested but it wasn't inside the EMR application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap these lines around:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='tt_hvr1.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You need to load jQuery before the code that uses it. Eg. notice how this fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/uPASm/ and this one doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/uPASm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.html()` function to replace the content of tooltip by adding the following in hover function

```
 $(".tooltip00").html(this.innerHTML);
```

Also you need to change

```
 $(".tooltip00").css("display", "block");
```

to

```
 $(".tooltip00").css("display", "none");
```

To hide the tooltip.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6ewnZ/3/)